# Getting confirm value in code behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

i have a pop up on the index change of a combo box and i need to get the result of the confirm box in the code behind:

```
Protected Sub service_list_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles service_list.SelectedIndexChanged  

Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "confirm", x.javaMsg("Do you
want to choose a date?"), True)

If user clicks ok 
GridView1.DataSource = x.selectCNT(service_list.SelectedValue)
GridView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

this is my function:

```
Public Function javaMsg(ByVal message As String) As String

    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("confirm('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")
    Return sb.ToString()

End Function
```

note that i'm using asp.net with vb.net

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran i need to bind the data when the user clicks ok if he clicks cancel i need to do something else...  so how can i get the result of the confirm box in the code behind?

Comment: Do you now how to bind data to grid view from javascript ?

Comment: @SainPradeep no i don't but actually i need to bind the data from the vb not from javascript ! i just want to get the result of the confirm box in the code behind not in javascript

Comment: Do you know Jquery ?  and jquery ui dialog  ?

Comment: @RameshRajendran i've already tried it and it did not work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that shows how to do it: [Call VB method from JavaScript](http://forums.asp.net/t/1393756.aspx)

It basically says there are 2 ways, Ajax or Postback.  Here is the postback method:

aspx file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 <!--
 function callServersideFunction()
 {
  var someValueToPass = 'Hello server';

 __doPostBack('CustomPostBack', someValueToPass);
 }
 // -->
 </script>
```

aspx.vb file:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
  ' Insure that the __doPostBack() JavaScript method is created...
  Me.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Me, String.Empty)


 If Me.IsPostBack Then
   Dim eventTarget As String
   Dim eventArgument As String

  If ( (Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET") Is Nothing)
    eventTarget = String.Empty
   Else
    eventTarget = Me.Request("__EVENTTARGET"))
   If ( (Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT") Is Nothing)
    eventArgument = String.Empty
   Else
    eventArgument = Me.Request("__EVENTARGUMENT"))

  If eventTarget = "CustomPostBack" Then
    Dim valuePassed As String = eventArgument
    ' Call your VB method here...
   End If
  End If
 End Sub
```